# Destructor Code for Recursive Binary Tree Deletion Not Working In Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, binary-tree

This question might be similar to some others out there; however, ***my question here is pertaining to a Visual C++ issue***. The following code for deleting a Binary Tree works fine with GNU's C++ compiler.

Tree_Node Class Definition:

```
class Tree_Node
{
    friend class Binary_Tree;

public:
    typedef int node_type;

    node_type& data()
    {
        return value;
    }

    void data(node_type key)
    {
        this->value = key;
    }

    Tree_Node(node_type key) : value(key) {}
    ~Tree_Node();


private:
    node_type value = 0;
    Tree_Node* right = nullptr;
    Tree_Node* left = nullptr;
};
```

Binary Tree Destructor Definition:

```
Binary_Tree::~Binary_Tree()
{
    deleteTree(root);
}

void Binary_Tree::deleteTree(Tree_Node* node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        deleteTree(node->left);
        deleteTree(node->right);

        cout << node->data();
        delete node;
    }
}
```

However, while giving Visual C++ a try, the same code is giving out a couple of strange  errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Tree_Node::~Tree_Node(void)" (??1Tree_Node@@QAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function "public: void * __thiscall Tree_Node::`scalar deleting
>   destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GTree_Node@@QAEPAXI@Z)
>   E:\Workspace\BinaryTree\BinaryTree\BinaryTree_Methods.obj
>
> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   E:\Workspace\BinaryTree\Debug\BinaryTree.exe

The problem seems to be arising specifically from the `delete node;` statement. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is Tree_Node.cpp compiled in the same project as Binary_Tree.cpp?

Comment: Well, they are part of the same project. The class definitions Tree_Node and BinaryTree are in a separate header File TreeHeader.h. Method definitions for Binary_Tree are in a file BinaryTree_Methods.cpp. However, are header files compiled in Visual C++

Comment: Hmm, everything seems fine. Headers are not "compiled" separately in VS (though they should still be included in the project, for intellisense and a few other cases). If they're both in the same project, the linker should be finding the destructor without any problem...

Comment: Check your `Tree_Node` and make sure there is either an *implemented* `~Tree_Node()` or there is NO `~Tree_Node();` declaration in the class decl. It looks like you're declaring one in the class decl, but not implementing it. Its an all-or-nothing deal. You have to either declare *and* implement it, or don't do either and live with the default destructor (which may not be right for your situation, but that is a different issue).

Comment: Show the definition of Node and the definition of the destructor if it was defined explicitly.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Please check the comment to the answer below.

Comment: @WhozCraig Just a side question: why did you say that using the default constructor (no declaration or definition) might not be right for this situation? Is using `=default` a bad idea then?

Comment: @Chatterjee *destructor*, and it may not be appropriate if there are things outside of default-destruction you need (i.e. you have your own cleanup you need beyond just allowing your held-value to wither). In most cases its fine to just live with default destruction, but there are times it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make a destructor for node?

Like Declare and define ~Tree_Node()

Comment: My bad! `=default` did the trick. I was initially pondering of a different deletion strategy, where `BinaryTree` would delete its `root` and the `Tree_Node` destructor would delete its `left` and `right` children, but instead tried this and forgot to implement the `Tree_Node` destructor. I'm surprised though how this worked with `g++` then?

Comment: @Chatterjee it is not the reason. Specifying = default is the definition of the destructor.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What I meant was that I forgot to define the `Tree_Node` destructor; I only declared it (see the updated code above). Defining it with `=default` made the code work.